# Show that a sequence of functions has a uniformly convergent subsequence on (-1,1)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, arzela-ascoli

I'm studying for my Real Analysis qualifying exam and I'm a little unsure of one question. I'm given that $f_k$ is a sequence of continuous functions  $(-1,1) \to \Bbb R$ such that $|f_k| \leq M$ for all $x$ and $k$. Let

$$g_k(x) = \int_a^x f_k(t)dt.$$

I have to show that this sequence, $g_k$, has a uniformly convergent subsequence.

Now my first instinct is to try using Arzela-Ascoli, but I'm a little iffy on whether it's applicable since the domain is an open interval. So I was thinking maybe I could extend $g_k$ to $[-1,1]$, but I'm not sure if I can do that or how I would go about showing I can.

Is this the right direction? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint 1:** Use the boundedness of $f_k$ to show that $g_k$ is **uniformly** continuous on $(-1,1)$.

**Hint 2**: Show that an uniformly continuous function on $(-1,1)$ can be extended to a continuous function on $[-1,1]$.  (this is a more general phenomena: any uniformly continuous function can be extended to the completion of your space).

Comment: Okay, I thought that was the direction I was supposed to go in, but was having trouble finding out whether I could in fact extend a uniformly continuous function to its closure. Would I be able to use the fact that $g_k$ is the anti-derivative of a continuous function to show uniform continuity?

Comment: Never mind the part about continuity--either way it's easy enough to show that $g_k$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: @five99one Yes, that part is easy. It follows for free from standard properties of the integral. But the approach from your first comment also works: if $h$ is a function which is differentiable and has a bounded derivative, then by the MVT $$\left| \frac{h(x)-h(y)}{x-y} \right| = |h'(c)| \leq M$$ It follows that $$|h(x)-h(y)| \leq M |x-y|$$ From where uniform continuity follows imediatelly. This proof basically boils down to "bounded derivative" $\Rightarrow$ "Lipshitz" $\Rightarrow$ uniformly continuous, but I still think that the obvious integral proof is easier.